# In extjs how to use group radioButton

Tags: extjs, radio-group

I am working in extjs. i want to create view such that it will dislay 20 questions and each of question along with its options with radio buttons.These questions i am retreiving from database using yii framework. I had created view as =

```
View=
```

Question.js

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.question.Question', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Balaee.view.question.QuestionView'],
    id: 'QuestionId',
    alias: 'widget.question',
    title: 'Question',
    height: 180,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'questionView',
    },

    ], //end of items square
    buttons: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        fieldLabel: 'Vote',
        name: 'vote',
        formBind: true,
        text: 'submit',
        action: 'voteAction',
    }]
});
```

QuestionView.js

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.question.QuestionView', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.View',
    id: 'QuestionViewId',
    alias: 'widget.questionView',
    store: 'Question',
    config: {
        tpl: '<tpl for=".">' +
            '<div id="main">' +
            '</br>' +
            '<b>Question :-</b> {question}</br>' +
        //'<p>-------------------------------------------</p>'+

        '<tpl for="options">' + // interrogate the kids property                  within the data
        '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="opt" >&nbsp{option} </p>' +
            '</tpl></p>' +

            '</div>' +
            '</tpl>',
        itemSelector: 'div.main',
    }
});
```

So how to display options using group radio buttons so that after click of submit button, it will give me all user's selected radio buttons option as user's option.Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want several questions on one page, right??

First you have to change your tpl a little bit

```
            '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="opt{questionNumber}" >&nbsp{option} </p>'+
```

After that you can simple query for the inputs using [Ext.dom.Query](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query):

```
xtype:'button',
fieldLabel:'Vote',
name:'vote',
FormBind:true,
text:'submit', 
listeners: { 
    click: function(btn,e,eOpts) {
         var answers = Ext.core.DomQuery.select("input[type='radio']:checked");

          //e.g.: sending the data via AJAX-call to the server
          Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: ' //e.g. answers.php',
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
                answers: answers
             },
            success: function(response) {
               //do something
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                //do something
            }
    }
 }
```

This will return all checked radio-buttons!

Comment: thanx sir for your reply. I changed tpl as above. But where to include above query? Will it be on submit button's click event? Actully i am very new to extjs. So can you please help me?

Comment: You need a click-listner! For example you can create the listener directly by the button (xtype:'button').

Answer (score 0):

Check this example , i think it's useful http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/form/check-radio.html